# How can i verify the Cucumber jars while using it with selenium

Tags: java, selenium, cucumber, cucumber-junit

I am trying to incorporate cucumber with selenium using Java . I have included the following jars into my classpath .

```
  1. cucumber-core-1.2.0.jar
  2. cucumber-java-1.2.0.jar
  3. cucumber-junit-1.2.0.jar
  4. cucumber-jvm-deps-1.0.3.jar
  5. cucumber-reporting-0.0.2.jar
  6. cobertura-1.8.jar
```

But when i try to run the files , i am getting this following error .

```
 cucumber.runtime.CucumberException: Couldn't find /cucumber/formatter/formatter.js. Is cucumber-html on your classpath? Make sure you have the right version.
```

Please tell me if i would need to add other version of jars or new jar ???

Comment: The issue is resolved by downloading cucumber-html-0.2.3.jar and add it into the classpath .Thanks

Comment: Is there a maven option? What if I use io.cucumber instead of info.cukes?

Answer (score 0):

You have missed cucmber sources jar (eg: cucumber-html-0.2.2-sources.jar) in the class path. Try downloading the latest jar from maven [1]

[1] https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.cukes

Comment: What if I use io.cucumber instead of info.cukes?